# Responsive image carousel slider component with inertia mouse/touch & multiple images with different aspect ratios

Tags: javascript, image, styled-components, web-component, photo-gallery

I struggle to find an image slider component with ALL next features:

1. Multiple images with various aspect ratios visible at the same time in the carousel (landscape/portrait)
2. Lazy loading (for efficiency of showing many images)
3. Scrolling by mouse and touch with inertia (for UX = the faster you roll the faster and further it scrolls the images)
4. Scrolling by button (and preferably also keyboard arrows)
5. Responsive to fit various desktop and mobile devices and to be used in various sizes on the screen and work on all devices reliably
6. On-click and on-change actions on particular images

Whatever component I found misses at least some of the above.

The closest is an EditorX I used to prototype the solution I need: [hoursfrom.world](https://www.hoursfrom.world/).

But on top of being clumsy, buggy and slow (that forced the insane splitting the page to iframes) it does not support the inertia sliding when the images are already scrolling. One needs to wait for images to stop before he can scroll further. And it's even more annoying that if he tries to scroll while images are already scrolling, he might trigger prev/next browser navigation.

Do I miss something? Isn't there really any component matching all above?

Comment: StackOverflow is for helping you with your code(snippets), that is why people vote to close your question.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I see there answered questions helping with choosing the right component for the given scenario as well. With the growing complexity, choosing the right framework or component for the task or scenario is quite an important work as well.